# How to migrate to Spring boot 3 when relying on a third-party library that still uses javax instead of jakarta api?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jira-rest-api

We are in the process of migrating our project to Spring Boot 3 and while we refactored our code to use the new `jakarta` api (instead of `javax`) there is one third-party library that still uses `javax` and unfortunately there is no available `jakarta` version published yet.

The dependency is `jira-rest-java-client-core` and can be found [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.jira/jira-rest-java-client-core/5.2.4). They seem to be using `javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder`.

What happens in such cases?

Delay the migration until there is a new Spring Boot 3-compatible version of the library or include the `javax` api via some other legacy dependency e.g. [jersey-client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-client) ?  Will it cause any issues down the line having both `jakarta` and `javax` in the classpath ?

Answer (score 1):

Having both `jakarta` and `javax` in the classpath will not cause any material issues, besides the IDE prompting both imports when a 'duplicated' class name is used.

The decision on whether to migrate to Spring Boot 3.0.x now or later (and use dependencies with pre jdk17 package naming) depends on what is driving this, eg spring-boot dependency vulnerabilities, functionality, etc. It may be unavoidable.

My preference is to wait for 3.1.x so that issues caused by the jump to jdk17 are bedded down and SO has more questions and useful answers.